# Run multiple Celery chains at the same time

Tags: python, django, celery

I have Celery tasks chain that I call with `apply_async`. Each task in chain depends on the result from previous task.

Basically the worklof looks like this:

1. Fetch data from DB.
2. For each fetched row run chain with tasks.

Behaviour that I want to achieve is to run multiple chains at one time. But it seems like it runs them in a row, not simultaneously. How to fix this issue?

Comment: Are you calling `apply_async` at the "run chains" stage? Are you using more than one worker?

Comment: @duhaime no, I'm using only one worker. Code looks like this:

`@shared_task
def tasks_runner():
    chain = (task1.s() | task2.s() | task3.s())

    chain.apply_async()`

Comment: If you want to run multiple chains simultaneously, I would create a pool of chains and run them in an asynchronous manner, using more than one worker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run chains at once you will need to run more than one worker.

Comment: How about concurrency? Let's say I'll pass flag --concurrency 10 for each worker, then what kind of behavior I'll achieve then?

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant - you'll need to run multiple worker processes. The best way to find out what kind of behavior you'll achieve is to actually try it.